# if (any(foo == (/1,2,3,4/)) instead of if ((foo == 1).or.(foo == 2).or. ...?

Tags: if-statement, optimization, fortran

I have numerous if statements that read something like

```
if ((foo == 1).or.(foo == 2).or.(foo == 3).or.(foo == 4)) then
   call bar1
end if
if ((foo == 3).or.(foo == 4).or.(foo == 5).or.(foo == 6)) then
   call bar2
end if
```

Are there any reasons (w.r.t. speed, style, etc.) to **not** use something like this?

```
if (any(foo == (/1,2,3,4/))) call bar1
if (any(foo == (/3,4,5,6/))) call bar2
```

In my real example the numbers are not necessarily sequentially. So I can not use

```
if ((foo >= 1).and.(foo <=4)) call bar1
if ((foo >= 3).and.(foo <=6)) call bar1
```

the *overlap* of the two if conditions is deliberate, which makes it in my understanding impossible to use the SELECT CASE statement.

Comment: If the lists really are composed of integer constants I think I might use `If( Any( foo == meaningfully_named_parameter_array ) )...` but that is minor. Otherwise I agree with @HighPerformanceMark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

High Performance Mark has answered most of your question, but allow me to present a nice alternative method.

Fortran allows [operator overloading](https://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/opover), and this allows us to overload `.in.` to see if an item is in a list. The code for this would look like

```
module in_module
  implicit none
  
  interface operator(.in.)
    module procedure integer_in_integer_list
  end interface
contains
  function integer_in_integer_list(item, list) result(output)
    integer, intent(in) :: item
    integer, intent(in) :: list(:)
    logical :: output
    
    output = any(item==list)
  end function
end module
```

And then your code simply becomes

```
if (foo .in. [1,2,3,4]) call bar1
if (foo .in. [3,4,5,6]) call bar2
```

In my opinion this is the cleanest way of doing this, and it should have similar performance to other methods. You can overload `.in.` to take other types (including user-defined types) as needed.

Answer (score 1):

With regards to the speed part of the question - if this is a concern for you then test and measure.  If you don't think it's worth your time testing and measuring then (a) you're probably right, I don't think that I have ever worked on a significant Fortran program where the speed differences between the two approaches could have been of material interest; and (b) it's not worth my time either!

As to the style - that part of the question is off-topic here - but I don't find it all objectionable, though I might write a wee function with signature `memberQ(foo, list)` and the obvious implementation.